# (Bluetooth) Registering SDP record on local server in C on Linux

Tags: c, linux, bluez

I am doing work on an application using Bluetooth and I want to register a new record on a local SDP server using C. I am using the BlueZ library but I am getting a segfault when trying to register my service.

The code goes as follows:

```
sdp_session_t *register_service()
{
    uint32_t service_uuid_int[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0xABCD };
    uint8_t rfcomm_channel = 11;
    bdaddr_t interface;
    const char *service_name = "BlueFind";
    const char *service_dsc = "Service to locate";
    const char *service_prov = "BlueFind Inc.";

    uuid_t root_uuid, l2cap_uuid, rfcomm_uuid, svc_uuid;
    sdp_list_t *l2cap_list = 0, 
               *rfcomm_list = 0,
               *root_list = 0,
               *proto_list = 0, 
               *access_proto_list = 0;
    sdp_data_t *channel = 0;

    bacpy(&interface, BDADDR_ANY);

    sdp_record_t *record = sdp_record_alloc();

    // set the general service ID
    sdp_uuid128_create( &svc_uuid, &service_uuid_int );
    sdp_set_service_id( record, svc_uuid );

    // make the service record publicly browsable
    sdp_uuid16_create(&root_uuid, PUBLIC_BROWSE_GROUP);
    root_list = sdp_list_append(0, &root_uuid);
    sdp_set_browse_groups( record, root_list );


    // set l2cap information
    sdp_uuid16_create(&l2cap_uuid, L2CAP_UUID);
    l2cap_list = sdp_list_append( 0, &l2cap_uuid );
    proto_list = sdp_list_append( 0, l2cap_list );


    // set rfcomm information
    sdp_uuid16_create(&rfcomm_uuid, RFCOMM_UUID);
    channel = sdp_data_alloc(SDP_UINT8, &rfcomm_channel);
    rfcomm_list = sdp_list_append( 0, &rfcomm_uuid );
    sdp_list_append( rfcomm_list, channel );
    sdp_list_append( proto_list, rfcomm_list );


    // attach protocol information to service record
    access_proto_list = sdp_list_append( 0, proto_list );
    sdp_set_access_protos( record, access_proto_list );


    // set the name, provider, and description
    sdp_set_info_attr(record, service_name, service_prov, service_dsc);
    sdp_session_t *session = 0;

    // connect to the local SDP server, register the service record, and 
    // disconnect
    session = sdp_connect( BDADDR_ANY, BDADDR_LOCAL, SDP_RETRY_IF_BUSY );


    sdp_device_record_register(session, &interface, &record, SDP_RECORD_PERSIST);


    // cleanup
    sdp_data_free( channel );
    sdp_list_free( l2cap_list, 0 );
    sdp_list_free( rfcomm_list, 0 );
    sdp_list_free( root_list, 0 );
    sdp_list_free( access_proto_list, 0 );

    return session;
}
```

This is very similar to the implementation of *sdptool* from the BlueZ tools. I have narrowed my problem down to the line:

```
sdp_device_record_register(session, &interface, &record, SDP_RECORD_PERSIST);
```

but I don't know how to overcome this. Are there any other functions that I can use to register the service? Or I am I using the function wrong?

I am running this project on a Raspberry Pi using Jessie but I also get this on my Ubuntu VM running 18.04.3 LTS.

Comment: At a minimum you should have basic error checking. That will make your program more robust as well as greatly aid your debugging. In particular, check the result of  `sdp_connect` before proceeding to use `session`. Same goes for the `_alloc` function calls.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me too. You have to run the program as superuser. Other users does not have permissions to register SDP records. At least it looks like that, because non-root users does not have permissions to read/write to `/var/run/sdp`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this [example](https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x604.html). To print correct error messages, I've added this code to `register_service` function:

```c
    // connect to the local SDP server, register the service record, and 
    // disconnect
    session = sdp_connect(BDADDR_ANY, BDADDR_LOCAL, SDP_RETRY_IF_BUSY);
    if (session == NULL) {
            err = errno;
            goto CLEANUP;
    }
    if (sdp_record_register(session, record, 0) != 0) {
            err = errno;
            goto CLEANUP;
    }

CLEANUP:
    // cleanup
    sdp_data_free(channel);
    sdp_list_free(l2cap_list, 0);
    sdp_list_free(rfcomm_list, 0);
    sdp_list_free(root_list, 0);
    sdp_list_free(access_proto_list, 0);
    
    if (err != 0) {
            errno = err;
    }
    return session;
```

And then, check it in `main`:

```c
        sdp_session_t* session = register_service();
        if (session == NULL) {
                perror("register service");
                return 1;
        }
```

After changes, it prints the reason of the error (it was "register service: No such file or directory" and "register service: Permission denied") messages for me. So it's much easier to understand what's the cause of these errors.